# Retrieve an object from json

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

I have a JSON and using retrofit made a RecyclerView. Now I am going to each item in recyclerview has a detail activity. So I create another activity for this purpose with new call request.

Here is JSON:

```
[
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "A",
        "imageurl": "http://192.168.43.200/myproject/a.jpg"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "B",
        "imageurl": "http://192.168.43.200/myproject/b.jpg"
      }, 
    ...
    ]
```

and API interface for get all JSON objects:

```
@GET("/myproject/json")
    Call<List<Alphabet>> getAlphabets();

@GET("/myproject/json/{id}")
Call<Alphabet> getAlphabet(@Path("id") int id);
```

detail.java :

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        id = bundle.getInt("id");

        ApiInterface request = RetrofiBiulder.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
        Call<Alphabet> call = request.getAlphabet(id);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Alphabet>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Alphabet> call, Response<Alphabet> response) {
                Alphabet alphabet = response.body();
                if(response.isSuccessful()){

                    txtId.setText(String.valueOf(alphabet.getProductid()));
                txtNmae.setText(alphabet.getProductname());
                Glide.with(Detail.this).load(alphabet.getImageurl()).into(imgDetail);}

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Alphabet> call, Throwable t) {
            }
        });
```

Why it  does not work?

Comment: Pl give code that you have written in activity/fragment class to call getAlphabet() method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided your API supports this, you can add a query parameter to the retrofit interface method:

```
@GET("/myproject/json")
Call<Alphabet> getAlphabet(@Query("id") String id);
```

Or if your API expects the `id` as a path parameter:

```
@GET("/myproject/json/{id}")
Call<Alphabet> getAlphabet(@Path("id") String id);
```

Comment: I'm use Wampserver on localhost. I have successful request in Postman or in browser with (http://localhost/myproject/json) but I do not know how could successful request with ((http://localhost/myproject/json/1) for a specific objoct in JSON array.

Comment: @Amir Does you service support `localhost/myproject/json/1`? Are you able to get response for this from Postman/Browser?

Comment: and now Stackoverflow banned me to ask question any more!

Comment: @Amir Happy to help :)